# I need a font from a webpage

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have tried right clicking and inspecting element on the navigation bar on the top right of this web page:

http://www.southwest-heart.com/

I want to find out what font they are using where it says "Launch", "Heart" etc.. 
The only font family i can find is this one:

```
font-family: SouthwestSans-Regular,Arial,sans-serif;
```

How would i go about obtaining the font they are using?

Thanks.

Comment: because no one else said it - I am pretty sure they hold a form of copy right or licence onto that font, so you better NOT "simply use it"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use google chrome's [WhatFont(plugin)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en) to scanner and know the font information. I think you should try it, or look for a similar plugin for your browser.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly get this font from this website

[Your font will be downloaded by your browser after clicking this link](http://www.southwest-heart.com/fonts/SouthwestSansW01-Regular.ttf)

Answer (score 0):

See this-

http://fontsinuse.com/uses/319/southwest-airlines

and this

http://www.monotype.com/resources/case-studies/type-with-heart-for-southwest-airlines/

It's a custom font so you may not be able to get it but maybe you can find something similar...

Answer (score 0):

There is another font-family on class:

```
 .nav_toggle_menu a .nav_label {
    font-family: SouthwestSans-Bold,Arial,sans-serif;
 }
```

The font-family that you are searching for is **SouthwestSans-Bold**

Answer (score 0):

@NAjzero Definitely- you can't use fonts that you do not have a license for!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like only a very slight difference to Tahoma.  Playing with Font weight and letter spacing with Tahoma and css would give you near enough the same (in my opinion).